# What is the subset that represents well a netflow dataset?

Tags: network

I want to analyze a Netflow dataset by using a sliding window, therefore, I would like to know what should be taken into consideration when splitting the data?
The parameter that I am considering is the window size. Any guidance/reference on how to choose this parameter would be appreciated.

Comment: Netflow is not a security technology. I'm not sure you have asked this in the correct place.

Comment: How you split the data and what parameters to use is completely dependent on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @schroeder IDSs are designed to work by analyzing collected network traffic. I should have mentioned that my question falls in the context of security : anomaly detection.

Comment: But your question is not about anomaly detection, it's about netflow windows. You want to use the result in an anomaly detection function, but that's tangential.

Comment: Even if this was on topic here, you have not defined the problem space or defined what parameters matter to you. All you have said is, "I want to split the window"

Comment: @schroeder Let me try making it clearer and less abstract.   I am currently working on offline anomaly-based intrusion detection, I use unsupervised machine learning techniques to analyze Netflow data (similar to the NSL-KDD dataset). I want to explore the data by splitting them into subsets (sliding windows) that will be analyzed sequentially.

My question is about the appropriate way to split the data as I need subsets that are well representative of the whole dataset(collected in one day for example).

Comment: Which subsets are more appropriate: time-based (flows collected over a period of time) or size-based (fixed number of flows)? What is the appropriate period of time, in the case of time-based, and what is the subset size in the latter case?

Comment: All of those details are extremely helpful. I have done exactly what you have described. As for "appropriate", again, I am not sure how we can possibly answer that for you. It depends on the factors you want to identify and the statistical significance of the resulting windows based on your data set. It also depends on the type and nature of the flows and the focus of your anomaly definitons. I think this is more of a data science question than a security question.